# Passing a command to a mainwindow from a different viewmodel

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I'm new to WPF and learning more about MVVM, and I've come across a problem. So I have my `mainwindow.xaml` with its code and implementation mostly based on the view model `FileMenuCommands`, now I've created another view model called `AboutMenuCommands` and I want to pass a command (the help command) from here to the main window, but when I try to do that the compiler doesn't find my function.

What do I need to do in order to pass a command from another view model in an XAML?

Code from mainWindow:

```
<Window x:Class="Notepad___.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Notepad___.ViewModel"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="Notepad+++" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Window.DataContext>
        <local:FileMenuCommands/>
    </Window.DataContext>
    <Window.InputBindings>
        <KeyBinding Key="O" Modifiers="Ctrl" Command="{Binding Path=Open}" />
        <KeyBinding Key="N" Modifiers="Ctrl" Command="{Binding Path=New}" />
    </Window.InputBindings>
<Grid>
        <Menu Name="MainMenu" Height="Auto" Width="Auto" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Top">
            <MenuItem Header="_File" FontSize="14" >
                <MenuItem Header="_New" InputGestureText="Ctrl+N" Command="{Binding Path=New}">
                    <MenuItem.ToolTip>
                        <ToolTip>Create a new file.</ToolTip>
                    </MenuItem.ToolTip>
                </MenuItem>
                <MenuItem Header="Open" InputGestureText="Ctrl+O" Command="{Binding Path=Open}">
                    <MenuItem.ToolTip>
                        <ToolTip>Open a file.</ToolTip>
                    </MenuItem.ToolTip>
                </MenuItem>
                <MenuItem Header="_Save" InputGestureText="Ctrl+S">
                    <MenuItem.ToolTip>
                        <ToolTip>Saves a file in the current location if it already exists, if not creates a prompt.</ToolTip>
                    </MenuItem.ToolTip>
                </MenuItem>
                <MenuItem Header="_Save As" Command="{Binding Path=SaveAs}">
                    <MenuItem.ToolTip>
                        <ToolTip>Saves the file in the location prompted by the user in the format they desire.</ToolTip>
                    </MenuItem.ToolTip>
                </MenuItem>
                <MenuItem Header="_Exit" InputGestureText="Ctrl+X">
                    <MenuItem.ToolTip>
                        <ToolTip>Exits the application.</ToolTip>
                    </MenuItem.ToolTip>
                </MenuItem>
            </MenuItem>

            <MenuItem Header="_Search" FontSize="14" >
                <MenuItem Header="_Find" InputGestureText="Ctrl+F">
                    <MenuItem.ToolTip>
                        <ToolTip>Finds the occurences of the input word / set of characters.</ToolTip>
                    </MenuItem.ToolTip>
                </MenuItem>
                <MenuItem Header="_Replace" InputGestureText="Ctrl+R">
                    <MenuItem.ToolTip>
                        <ToolTip>Replaces the input word / set of characters.</ToolTip>
                    </MenuItem.ToolTip>
                </MenuItem>
                <MenuItem Header="_Replace All" >
                    <MenuItem.ToolTip>
                        <ToolTip>Replaces all the occurences of the input word / set of characters.</ToolTip>
                    </MenuItem.ToolTip>
                </MenuItem>
            </MenuItem>
            <MenuItem Header="_Help" FontSize="14" Command="{Binding Source=Help}"> // this is where i'm trying to pass my command from another xaml
                <MenuItem Header="_About" >
                    <MenuItem.ToolTip>
                        <ToolTip>A few words about the application and who made it</ToolTip>
                    </MenuItem.ToolTip>
                </MenuItem>
            </MenuItem>
        </Menu>
```

AboutMenuCommand.cs

```
using Notepad___.View;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Input;

namespace Notepad___.ViewModel
{
    class AboutMenuCommands
    {
        private ICommand m_help;

        private void HelpPage(object parameter)
        {
            var aboutPage = new About();
            aboutPage.ShowDialog();
        }

        public ICommand Help
        {
            get
            {
                if (m_help == null)
                    m_help = new RelayCommand(HelpPage);
                return m_help;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your MainWindowViewModel should get the viewmodel instance from your about page. The about command should be implemented in MainWindowViewModel and call the viewmodel from the About page.

I had such questions several month ago and came out with a mvvm framework which does really help to understand the principles of mvvm.

But i did not want to give up the control to a framework which i can not look into and so i found [mvvmgen](https://github.com/thomasclaudiushuber/mvvmgen) .

So take a look at the doc in mvvmgen and you will find the answer to your mvvm questions.